# Font wont export out

Tags: sifr

I can get sIFR to work but it will only display the bold version of the font I have exported. I checked the report and it seems to be stripping out any font weight that is not bolded in flash. I exported two different files to test, the first with regular and bold and the second with medium and semibold in both cases only the bolded weights were exported. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When exporting the Flash movie, make sure at least one character in the text field has the styles applied to it. Then it should export fine.

Comment: I messed around with the order and it seems it will export the first two styles and ignore the second two (the weight doesnt matter just the order). It seems strange I've never run into this issue before but it doesn't seem to be an issue with the typeface. Have you heard of this before?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like the other styles are actually different font families. In sifr-config, try explicitly specifying the font family.

Comment: They're all from the same family, just different weights. I think I'm only going to need regular and bold weights with this project so it's not going to be a big deal. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - could not make the font 'bold' style work, and I even whanted my fonts BlackItalic to work. Messing around and reading your post and Marks answer made me try to apply the BlackItalic style to the very first word in the provided fla file. Keeping the css style 'font-weight: normal;' in the config java code was successful!

Until I read some new posts about this I will follow the work flow making individual swf files for every font style - normally I only want to use one or to styles anyway.