# sIFR Only the first font-style of glyph in my swf will display, cannot seem to call up the others

Tags: sifr, styling, embedding, glyph, text-styling

I've uploaded my .swf with bold, normal and italic glyphs of the font embedded. I then go to my sifr-config.js file to style the text using CSS. All properties except the font-style:italic; and font-weight:bold; are effective.

In fact, when I try to use these properties the flash text doesn't show up at all.

But if I go back into my flash file and change the first glyph from "normal" to "bold" or "italic" then re-export, it'll display the Flash text as whatever style I've just changed that first glyph to.

Here's my CSS all the properties except font-weigh and font-style work:

```
sIFR.replace(ronnia, {
  selector: 'h1, logo-text',
  wmode: 'transparent',
  css: '.sIFR-root { font-size:200px; background-color:none; color: #000000; text-transform: uppercase; font-style:Italic; display:block;}'
});
```

I'm really new to the sIFR thing, any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code says `Italic` with a capital I. Flash can be picky with its CSS support, so that might be a problem. Other than that, it'd help if you could add a link to a demo page.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION (eeehhh - work-around):

It's an export from flash-problem - I read some other posts about flash not exporting style 3 and 4 of the fla file.( [Font wont export out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138362/font-wont-export-out) )

This made me try this: I applied 'bold' as style to the first word in the sifr3-r436- fla file (the word 'Make') and exported it. In the demo index.html file i called this swf file but I DID NOT change the css code part to bold (font-weight: normal) - for the first time I was able to display the 'bold' style of the font using sIFR.

I think I'll stick to a work flow making seperate swfs for each font-weight.

Mark, I guess a lot of people struggle with this - are you going to tell people about this problem on the sIFR documentation site?

PROBLEM:
I also struggle with that problem. Only 'normal' works with some of the fonts. One of the fonts I'm trying to use don't have 'BoldItalic' so I set this to 'bold' - could that be the reason for 'bold' to fail?

Have anybody solved this problem yet? If not I'll try to set up a demo page for Mark to explore.

Like Jay I wonder if this is a font problem - are problem with some fonts a known issue?

Actually 'bold' 'italic' 'bold&italic' is a problem with almost all the fonts I try out. Only success with verdana and georgia...

What critical info have I missed? Do I do something wrong in the fla file?

I tried something to check whats doing what - I applied the bold font style to the 'normal' word in the fla file - but that does not have any effect. I guess it's just a question of embedding the font style in te swf-file.